# Trying to install R generates unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, r, dependencies

I've followed the instalation of R (first r-base) as I always did - adding mirror, genereate the correct key, then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install. But now I'm getting unmet dependencies error with some packages.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre-headless : Depende: openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~u3-2.1.1) but it is not installable
 libqt5feedback5 : Depende: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
 libqt5quick5 : Depende: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installable
 libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 : Depende: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140408.1) but it is not installable
 openjdk-7-jre : Depende: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated flaws, this can be caused by packets held.
```

Already ran the common commands to tackle the error as other askubuntu pages suggests.

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install

But none of them solve problem.

Anyone could help me?